# Can I use VC9 compiled PHP with Apache?

Tags: php, apache, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2008

According to the Windows Binaries download page http://windows.php.net/download/

> Do **NOT** use VC9 version with apache.org binaries

Does this still hold? The only VC6 binaries are for PHP 5.2 and I believe that VC6 is no longer supported by Microsoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using VC6 Apache (which is what apache.org builds) will NOT work with PHP VC9.

PHP.net suggests for you to use Apache binaries from [ApacheLounge](http://apachelounge.com/), they are built with VC9 and will work.

Comment: Ah! If only I could read properly! Thank you - that makes sense!

Comment: Could you explain why this is?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler Because of how they interact with each other, they need to be compiled with the same compiler version.

Comment: Where is the best/safest place to get PHP 64-bit?